how do I get LINES and COLS updated if I user newterm() instead of initscr()?
migrating my existing code from using initscr() (which created the stdscr) ..
.. to using newterm() for multi monitor use.
I never used the stdscr but created other WINDOW's over it.
Trouble is just swapping the function means I no longer have a stdscr and can't seem to find a way to get LINE and COLS to update.
I need them to build other WINDOW objects that don't overlap and shrink properly when keyresize occurs.
Any ideas?

newterm() returns a SCREEN* pointer. I assume the SCREEN structure contains these values for the selected screen.

Can't seem to find anything on the struct SCREEN.

The "SCREEN" typedef seems to be opaque.

Yeah, I've been trying to find a function that does this. But I'm not very familiar with ncurses.

newterm (just like initscr) sets the global values stdscr and curscr.  But those are pointers.  The return value from newterm is a SCREEN pointer (also opaque), and you can use set_term to switch between screens that you have initialized with newterm.  When you switch screens, the pointers for stdscr and curscr are updated.
LINES and COLS also are screen-specific global values. Changing LINES and COLS has little effect on the internal behavior of the curses library.  These global values are provided for applications to use (or modify using the library functions).  Modifying them directly will not work well.
Use wresize to change the size of an existing window.

Thanks Thomas .. one quick question .. CHATGPT keeps saying that resizeterm() is necessary for what I am trying to do.

Tried wresize() .. not working .. my issue now is that the WINDOW has to move as well as resize .. so I guess I need another function that does both?

mvwin moves a window.  There is no curses function which does both.
